# Why am I getting this make error w/ 0.4.0rc1 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Building 0.4.0rc1 in Ububtu via make -f makefile.unix returns the following errors/warnings:

```
ui.cpp: In member function 'virtual void CMainFrame::OnIconize(wxIconizeEvent&)':
ui.cpp:488:25 warning: 'bool wxIconizeEvent::Iconized() const' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/wx-2.9/wx/event.h:2150)
ui.cpp:456:43 warning: 'bool wxIconizeEvent::Iconized() const' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/wx-2.9/wx/event.h:2150)
ui.cpp: in function 'void SetStartOnSytstemStartup(bool)':
ui.cpp:1808:39: error: 'class boost::filesystem3::path' has no member named 'native_file_string'
make: *** [obj/ui.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this? I'm guessing it's an issue with my libraries...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first two lines are just warnings that can be ignored. But the error is a [known issue](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/456) caused by Bitcoin's use of a deprecated API that was removed in your version of Boost. The [fix](https://github.com/NyuSan/bitcoin/commit/90c29c7a8a0a67df3122879303ed5e9abe17948f) is to modify `src/ui.cpp` around line 1809 as follows:

```
  {
     if (!fAutoStart)
     {
-        unlink(GetAutostartFilePath().native_file_string().c_str());
+        unlink(GetAutostartFilePath().c_str());
     }
     else
     {
```

(Remove the line marked with a **-** and replace it with the line marked with a **+**.)

Comment: Thank you David for your pinpoint accuracy and help. Your time is valued, and your contributions to the community are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, here are a few resources.

For 10.04 there is a good guide [here](http://lickthesalt.com/2010/08/19/compiling-bitcoin-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid/) and an additional resource [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/416/how-do-i-build-bitcoin-from-source-in-linux).

For 11.04 this question may be a [duplicate](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/522/how-to-build-bitcoin-from-source-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal/533#533).

Comment: I am running 11.04, but this is not a duplicate of that question. Thank you for the 10.04 resources though - maybe I will find something in there